# ¿Cómo agrupar y ordenar con linq por más de un campo?

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una lista y necesito  agrupar y  ordenar esta por los campos FechPago y Sucursal,
logre agruparla de esta manera pero me falta ordenarla

```
 var grupo = sucursal.Detalle.Where(x => x.CodEmpresa == codigoEmpresa).GroupBy(x => new {x.FechaPago, x.Sucursal});
```

faltaría agregarle el ***OrderBy (FechaPago, Sucursal)***
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Saludos luego del GroupBy usa de forma similar ThenBy. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-thenby-thenbydescending

Comment: Hola... RobertoLeOr .. no creo q sea lo que nesecito por que es por propiedades de la lista que deseo ordenarla

Comment: de la misma manera que te dice Roberto, tenes el orderBy, luego del groupby. Eso no te funciono?

Answer (score 1):

Para ver mejor la representacion de la query podrias usar la notacion linq

```
 var grupo = from d in sucursal.Detalle
               where d.CodEmpresa == codigoEmpresa
               group d by new {d.FechaPago, d.Sucursal} into g
               order by g.Key.FechaPago, g.Key.Sucursal;
```

Creo que si usas metodos de extension te puede estar pasando lo que se explica aqui

[How do I order by after grouping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704482/how-do-i-order-by-after-grouping)

alli menciona que despues de agrupar si quieres ordenar deberias usar el `AsEnumerable()` o definir el `Select()`

```
 var grupo = sucursal.Detalle
                     .Where(x => x.CodEmpresa == codigoEmpresa)
                     .GroupBy(x => new {x.FechaPago, x.Sucursal})
                     .Select(x=> new {FechaPago = x.Key.FechaPago, Sucursal = x.Key.Sucursal})
                     .OrderBy(x=> x.FechaPago)
                     .ThenBy(x=> x.Sucursal);
```